# Troubles with sending POST request using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am once again trying to send a request to RNA Folding Servers, but I can't get the answer. Last time I resolved it by adding the required parameters that I did not write initially. This time I checked POST request data with a web sniffer and was sure that all required parameters were filled. However, there are still no answers from servers ( [RNAStructure](https://rna.urmc.rochester.edu/RNAstructureWeb/Servers/Predict1/Predict1.html) and [mfold](http://unafold.rna.albany.edu/?q=mfold/RNA-Folding-Form)). This is the code I used for RNAStructure server:

```py
import requests 

class RequestToRNAStruct:
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def request_rnastructure(self):
    example_seq = 'GGGCUAUUAGCUCAGUUGGUUAGAGCGCACCCCUGAUAAGGGUGAGGUCGCUGAUUCGAAUUCAGCAUAGCCCA'
    rnastruct_url = 'https://rna.urmc.rochester.edu/RNAstructureWeb/Servers/Predict1/Predict1.html'

    payload = {'seqTitle': 'example',
                'seqBox': example_seq,
                'Acids': 'RNA',
                'gamma': '1',
                'intercept': '-0.6',
                'iterations': '1',
                'loop': '30',
                'max': '2',
                'minHelix': '3',
                'percent': '10',
                'slope': '1,8',
                'structures': '20',
                'temperature': '310.15',
                'window': '3'}
    r = requests.post(rnastruct_url, data=payload)

    with open('RNAStructure_req.html', 'wb') as request_file:
        request_file.write(r.content)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems you are sending request to a wrong endpoint. But it will not work either you change the last part of url to `Runner.php`. Try selenium or other headless browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @marmeladze pointed out, the endpoint you were using was wrong. You are trying to send a POST request to an HTML. The correct endpoint is that URL with the `Runner.php` PHP script indicated in the form.

```
https://rna.urmc.rochester.edu/RNAstructureWeb/Servers/Predict1/Runner.php
```

You can actually send the request to make the endpoint evaluate the RNA sequence. However, the response does not contain the result of the evaluation (see image below), so storing the HTML page won't help you.

[image: Capture of the HTML text of the response]

I improved your code to send the request to the correct endpoint, wait for the results, and finally download them in PDF, PS, and CT format in different files. I hope this helps you get what you needed

```py
import requests 
import time

class RequestToRNAStruct:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.rna_seq = 'GGGCUAUUAGCUCAGUUGGUUAGAGCGCACCCCUGAUAAGGGUGAGGUCGCUGAUUCGAAUUCAGCAUAGCCCA'
        self.options = {
            'seqTitle': 'example',
            'seqBox': self.rna_seq,
            'Acids': 'RNA',
            'gamma': '1',
            'intercept': '-0.6',
            'iterations': '1',
            'loop': '30',
            'max': '2',
            'minHelix': '3',
            'percent': '10',
            'slope': '1,8',
            'structures': '20',
            'temperature': '310.15',
            'window': '3'
        }

        self.form_url = 'https://rna.urmc.rochester.edu/RNAstructureWeb/Servers/Predict1/Runner.php'
        self.rochester_edu_host = 'http://rna.urmc.rochester.edu'
        self.attempt_sleep_time = 5

    def extract_server(self, subpath):
        init_string = 'server='
        end_string = '&key'

        server = subpath[subpath.find(init_string) + len(init_string) : subpath.find(end_string)]

        return server

    def extract_key(self, subpath):
        init_string = 'key='
        end_string = '&started'

        key = subpath[subpath.find(init_string) + len(init_string) : subpath.find(end_string)]

        return key

    def extract_results_url(self, content):
        # string just before link to results
        string_key = 'Click <a href="'
        # indexes of the string sequence in the content        
        init_index = content.find(string_key)
        end_index = content.find('"', init_index + len(string_key) + 1)

        # extracted URL
        url_subpath = content[init_index + len(string_key): end_index]
        url_subpath = url_subpath.replace('&amp;', '&')

        wait_for_results_url = self.rochester_edu_host + url_subpath
        self.server = self.extract_server(url_subpath)
        self.key = self.extract_key(url_subpath)

        return wait_for_results_url

    def request_calculations(self):
        content = ''
        with requests.post(self.form_url, data=self.options) as r:      
            content = r.text

        return content

    def request_results_page(self, wait_for_results_url):
        attempt = 0
        in_progress_search_string = 'Calculation in progress. Please wait.'
        result_page_text = ''

        # attempts to get results page URL
        print('Sending request to server "{server}":'.format(server=self.server))
        print(wait_for_results_url)

        while(True):
            attempt += 1    
            print('\n > Attempt: ' + str(attempt))

            with requests.get(wait_for_results_url) as r:
                result_page_text = r.text
                # with open('RNAStructure_req.html', 'wb') as request_file:
                #     request_file.write(r.content)

            if in_progress_search_string in result_page_text:
                print(in_progress_search_string)
                time.sleep(self.attempt_sleep_time)
            else:
                print('Results ready!')
                break

        return result_page_text

    def save_results_to_disk(self, result_page_text):
        results_url_first_slice = self.rochester_edu_host + '/RNAstructureWeb/Servers'
        init_index = result_page_text.find('id="1downloadsAll"')
        search_string = '<a href="../../'

        print('\nSaving results with key "{key}" to files...'.format(key=self.key))

        for i in range(3):
            init_index_url = result_page_text.find(search_string, init_index)
            init_index = init_index_url + len(search_string)
            url_params = result_page_text[ init_index_url + len(search_string) : result_page_text.find('" download', init_index_url) ]

            single_result_url = '{host}/{server}/{url_params}'.format(
                host=results_url_first_slice,
                server=self.server,
                url_params=url_params,
            )

            extension = single_result_url[ single_result_url.rfind('.') + 1 :]
            filename = '{key}.{extension}'.format(
                key=self.key,
                extension=extension
            )

            print('({step}/3) {extension}...'.format(
                step=i+1,
                extension=extension.upper()
            ))

            with requests.get(single_result_url) as r:
                with open(filename, 'wb') as result_file:
                    result_file.write(r.content)

    def request_rnastructure_results(self):
        # send request with RNA sequence and selected options to perform the calculations
        form_response_content = self.request_calculations()
        # extract results URL from HTML content
        wait_for_results_url = self.extract_results_url(form_response_content)
        # wait until calculations have been made
        result_page_text = self.request_results_page(wait_for_results_url)
        # save results in three different files (different formats)
        self.save_results_to_disk(result_page_text)

        print('\nDone!')


# call main function
RequestToRNAStruct().request_rnastructure_results()
```